# Request a preferred IP address for a specific WiFi connection on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

Is there a way to ask for a *preferred* IP address for a specific WiFi connection in Windows 7?

I have no control over the router so I'm not asking for a **static** address, but just to request the router to give a specific IP address if it's available and otherwise choose from what's free.

Comment: You'll probably have to use some sort of script or write a windows service to do this.  You can easily do the opposite of what you want in Windows, but the alternate network settings can only be for a "static" setup and only the primary can be DHCP or static.

Comment: you don't need control over the router to get a static ip.

Comment: @Moab but then what would happen if the requested IP address is already taken?

Comment: @traveh A battle, just set a static ip further down the range, beyond 100 is good. Routers always assign lower ips first.

Comment: @Moab but if it's still taken, would I get an alternate IP, or would I have to change the static IP address I'm requesting again?

Comment: You would have to change it.